# MVVM bind in Android

Tags: android, swift, kotlin

I write an Android application using Kotlin.
In swift for ios, I have written these code for MVVM but I do not know what I can use for Android

```
 view.pullToRefresh.tap.bind(to: viewmodel.didTapRefresh)
```

When write Rx code, I can use method bind. But I cannot find the same thing for Android.

Can you show me how you write these code in Kotlin? Thank you

Comment: Kotlin in swift for ios? Wtf.

Comment: Kotlin for Android. In Swift for Ios, I have editted my question

Comment: `pullToRefresh.setOnClickListener {  view -> viewmodel.didTapRefresh() }`

Comment: bind in swift is kind of Reactive thing

Comment: that is a swifts rx extension isn't it?

Comment: it is swift rxcocoa